# Graphics.DrawString inline font change C#

Tags: c#, graphics, compact-framework

I'm working on creating an application that will display JSON data in a nicely formatted paragraph.  The JSON data has things like a title, sub-title, body, etc.  In the body there can be links (which I just need to display as blue and underlined) And this is where I'm running into trouble.

The program is based on the .net Compact Framework and I'm only given a Graphics object along with the JSON object (and a rectangle, font, color).  Is there anyway to nicely draw a string of text with all of the links changed to the different color/font?

My thoughts have been to draw each individual word and just change the font right then when the word comes up.  This sounds very inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Thanks :)

Oh, p.s. If there is an easy way to determine the proper height of the rectangle in the DrawString method, so that no text is clipped, that would also be very helpful!

UPDATE:  I figured out my P.S. question :)
http://www.mobilepractices.com/2007/12/multi-line-graphicsmeasurestring.html

Comment: Is this a WinForms app on the compact framework? If not, can you tell us more about the app?

Comment: Yes, it is a WinForms app on the compact framework.  It's actually a new Facebook Client :)  I've been developing it on XDA-Developers for a couple of months now.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I ended up doing is adding a custom drawing method w/ special "Word" objects.  The Word object holds a string, color, and pointer to a font. I parsed the text into a dictionary of Word objects and then looped through all the objects and drew the text with the following sudo code

```
int maxWidth = Width
int curX = 0
int curY = 0

foreach word in words
    if curX > 0
        word = DrawWordUntilWidth(out curX, out curY, word, maxWidth)

    if word != null
        DrawWord(out curX, out curY, word, maxWidth)
```

`DrawWordUntilWidth` will mesure words in `word` (deliminated by spaces and "-") until `curX > maxWidth` and then draw the words that will fit, trunc the string in word, set curX to 0, set `curY += maxWordHeight` being the max height of the fonts used on that row. If all the words in `word` are used up, null is returned, else the trunc'ed word is returned.

`DrawWord` is very similar but runs on the assumption that curX is always = 0, so it can draw the whole string then set the curX and curY accordingly.

It works pretty well, as in there are few studders and it renders pretty smoothly.  If anyone has a better solution, please let  me know!